# How do I consume web service in objective -C using secured protocol like https

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ipad

I have a web service developed in C# that I am trying to consume on the iPad. The web service returns JSON which should be fairly simple to read.

Are there any good tutorials or examples for iPad application consuming web service over HTTPS protocol  out there ?

Answer (score 1):

do you know about http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use ?
its a really easy to use http-request framework.

in combination with http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/ it solved all my problems with objective-c and json-requests

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLRequest` ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) and `NSURLConnection` ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) are what you're looking for as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360452/https-on-iphone)